# Problems with the accuracy of values in System dynamics with multiple agents

Tags: anylogic, agent, systemdynamics

I have the problem that in my system Dynamics the genaugikeit of the values are not correct. I have several agents built in.
In the following figure you can see a flow and a stack. The flow is based on a table with values. For each hour in the simulation time there is a different value for the flow: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UBmg.png)
1 - 35
2 - 35
3 - 35
4 - 35
5 - 35
6 - 35
7 - 70...
Strangely, my stack does not get fuller?! What could be the reason?
Thanks a lot

Strangely, my stack does not get fuller?! What could be the reason?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set and understand your System-Dynamics solver settings correctly.

Properties are described [in the help](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/numerical-solvers.html#numerical-solvers-for-sd).

To get to the properties, click on your top-level model element in the Projects view (as below) and setup the properties as needed:
[image]